# Doesn't $in not work in in publish functions?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, meteor, publish-subscribe

In my Subscribe function, I pass-on a session variable (categoryArray), which is also an array to the Publish function, as specified in the code below:

```
Router.route('/MerchantLandingPage', {    
subscriptions: function(){
    var categoryArray = Session.get('category');

    return Meteor.subscribe('MerchantTrending', categoryArray)    
   }
});
```

In the Publish function, to ensure receipt, I `console.log` the `categoryArray`. This reflects in the terminal beautifully:
[image: successful reflection that the array is read by the publishing function]

Find below the corresponding code:

```
 Meteor.publish('MerchantTrending', function (categoryArray){
 var currentUser = this.userId;
 console.log ("Printing out Arrary>> " + categoryArray)
 return buyList.find({ who:"Merchant", itemCategory: { $in: [ categoryArray ] } }, {ownerId:currentUser }, {skip: 0, limit: 3});
```

});

My issue is that the `return buyList.find({ who:"Merchant", itemCategory: { $in: [ categoryArray ] } }, {ownerId:currentUser }, {skip: 0, limit: 3});` doesnt return back anything. Doesnt `$in`not workin in publish functions? Or am I somehow using the `$in` wrongly?

Kindly help!

Comment: have you try to run your query in something like robomongo?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your publication seems to be a problem with your query.

You are wrapping `ownerId: currentUser` in curly braces `{}`

Change your db query to the following:

```
buyList.find(
    { who:"Merchant", ownerId: currentUser, itemCategory: { $in: [ categoryArray ] } }, 
    {skip: 0, limit: 3}
);
```

If you want you can also just insert `this.userId` in to the query and remove the variable

```
buyList.find(
    { who:"Merchant", ownerId: this.userId, itemCategory: { $in: [ categoryArray ] } }, 
    {skip: 0, limit: 3}
);
```

Also, why are you using `skip: 0`? I think you can remove it

Answer (score 0):

@Sean Thanks for pointing out the curly braces. However removing them didn't resolve the issue at hand. I resolved the issue by removing the [ ] that wrapped the array in and the code. Now the code runs perfectly.

My code currently looks like this:

```
buyList.find(
{ who:"Merchant", ownerId: currentUser, itemCategory: { $in: categoryArray } }, 
{skip: 0, limit: 3}
);
```

Notice the omitted [ ] in the code.

Thank you anyway.